# The InteljIDEA not recognizing spring objects

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Hey Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue with IntelliJ IDEA where it's not recognizing Spring objects in my project. I've already set up the Spring framework, but it seems like IntelliJ is not picking it up. Autocomplete and import suggestions for Spring classes are not working.

I've tried refreshing the project, rebuilding, and invalidating caches, but the issue persists. Has anyone encountered a similar problem and found a solution? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which edition of IDEA do you have? Community or Ultimate?